# Content-type is not changed with curl

Tags: php, api, curl

I have a problem with api, I would like to create a GET query and send Authorization information in header
and Content-type but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Content-type won't change.

I post my code and the answer from the server.

What may be the problem?

```
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => '***',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => 1
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: ***',
  'Accept: application/json',
  'Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

response

```
Array
(
    [url] => *****
    [content_type] => text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 403
    [header_size] => 1055
    [request_size] => 263
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.063826
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004121
    [connect_time] => 0.016332
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.033503
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 16
    [speed_download] => 250
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 16
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.063806
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => ****
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => ****
    [local_port] => 43054
    [request_header] => GET *** HTTP/1.1
Host: ****
Authorization: *****
Accept: application/json
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8


)
error code: 1020
```

Answer (score 0):

If the request is a `GET` request, then this header will not be set at all. i.e. The field will not exist.

Comment: In the api documentation I have a GET request

Comment: If you can provide me with the link to the documentation I can take a look.